# Laravel/Dusk Swift_Events_EventListener not found

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

**Laravel Framework 5.4.13**

Basically I am working with [video tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/phpunit-testing-in-laravel/episodes/12)

But when I get to 4:30 in video i get this error:

> Fatal error: Interface 'Tests\Browser\Swift_Events_EventListener' not
>   found in C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\tests\Browser\MailTracker.php on line 46
>   PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Tests\Browser\Swift_Events_EventListener'
>   not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\tests\Browser\MailTracker.php on line
>   46

The code:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use App\User;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Chrome;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Tests\TestCase;

class MailTracker extends DuskTestCase
{
    public function SetUp()
    {
        parent::SetUp();

        Mail::getSwiftMailer()
            ->registerPlugin(new TestingMailEventListener);
    }
    /**
     * A basic browser test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        Mail::raw('Hello', function ($message){
            $message->to('foo@bar.com');
            $message->from('bar@foo.com');
        });
    }

    protected function seeEmailWasSent()
    {

    }
}

class TestingMailEventListener implements Swift_Events_EventListener
{
    public function beforeSendPerformed($event)
    {
        $message = $event->getMessage();
        dd($message);
    }
}
```

Any ideas what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
use Swift_Events_EventListener;
```

solved the problem, simple as that.